# Raspberry Pi Cam with WebRTC & UV4l driver (Sourcecode closed?)

Tags: javascript, webrtc, raspberry-pi2

I use the UV4L driver (RasPiCam) from [here](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14) with the WebRTC extension to get a continuous live view, streaming out from this HTTP [server](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=17) (RaspberryPi).

I would like to examine the sourcecode running on the server. Or is it closed source?

Comment: I've also looked long and hard for the UV4L source code but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.ics.com/blog/raspberry-pi-camera-module) webpage, the driver is closed-source.

There is now an open-source driver that has been integrated into the kernel as of December 2013.

To use it, simply update your Raspberry Pi and run:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

To have the device node /dev/video0 created. You can now use v4l2 compatible applications instead of uv4l, of which, there is greater availability.